# Clean the data based on condition pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame  as shown below

```
ID      Unit_ID      Price    Duration
1       A            200      2
2       B            1000     3
2       C            1000     3
2       D            1000     3
2       F            1000     3
2       G            200      1
3       A            500      2
3       B            200      2
```

From the above data frame if ID, Price and Duration are same then replace the Price by average (Price divided by count of Such combination).

For example from the above data frame from row 2 to 5 has same ID, Price and Duration, that means its count is 4, so the new Price = 1000/4 = 250.

Expected Output:

```
ID      Unit_ID      Price    Duration
1       A            200      2
2       B            250      3
2       C            250      3
2       D            250      3
2       F            250      3
2       G            200      1
3       A            500      2
3       B            200      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for `Series` with same size like original filled by counts, so possible divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].div(df.groupby(['ID','Price','Duration'])['Price'].transform('size'))
print (df)
   ID Unit_ID  Price  Duration
0   1       A  200.0         2
1   2       B  250.0         3
2   2       C  250.0         3
3   2       D  250.0         3
4   2       F  250.0         3
5   2       G  200.0         1
6   3       A  500.0         2
7   3       B  200.0         2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['ID','Price','Duration'])['Price'].transform('size'))
0    1
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```